# Battery voltage drop on load (speaker amplifier)

Tags: load, voltage

I have recently built a Bluetooth speaker. It is working well, but there is a problem when playing on high volume. The speaker has 2 parallel 18650 batteries for a power supply. I used booster modules to raise the voltage to 12V. While working on high volume and a bass tone appears, the battery's voltage drops a little and it comes back immediately until the next bass tone. Note that the voltage drop is detected with a multimeter on the booster module as well as on the battery's poles (before the module.)

Is there any way to prevent that voltage drop?

I tried to connect a capacitor of 10000 uF, parallel to the batteries but it didn't work.

The speaker amplifier can output around 14 W on speakers (7 watts on each channel.)

Comment: You’re at the limit due to the batteries internal resistance. Have you tried any supercapacitors? A few F should help. Or better batteries with lower internal resistance. Or more batteries in parallel.

Comment: @winny thank you. I will give super capacitors a try. I maybe add some batteries too... Thank you!

Comment: @matthewg You need a minimum of 10.5 V, plus circuit overhead requirements, to deliver 7 watts into 8 ohms. That's both plus and minus voltages, so bipolar supply. For 4 ohm speakers you still need about 7.5 V. And it must still be bipolar. I don't think a single rail of 12 V gets you to either place. Perhaps you could share with us your schematic?

Comment: @jonk It is a pam8610 module. It's connectors are gnd and 12v. Check the image on the following link.  https://images.app.goo.gl/sXYubuTxS9mRahGx5

Comment: It would make more sense to parallel the 10000uF cap with the 12V rail.

Comment: @Kartman I tried that too. Same thing happens

Comment: @matthewg I see. Class D and probably also bridged (I'll not bother to check that, though.)